# Trying to block similar malicious requests with nginx

Tags: regex, nginx

I'm having trouble trying to block a large amount of requests that are subtle variations of

```
/shop/?filter_product-categories=232%2C149%2C148%2C71%2C86&query_type_product-categories=or HTTP/1.1
```

where only the alphanumeric chunk changes. I've tried using

```
location ~ /(.*)([^a-z]*)query_type_product-categories=or(.*) {
  return 403;
}
```

and several different variations, but have yet to have any luck. I'm admittedly quite new to nginx and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your regex reduces to this `query_type_product-categories=or`. What are you trying to match?

Comment: I'd like to match the whole thing, while accounting for potential differences in the alphanumeric part. Suffice to say I'm a little confused with how regex works within an nginx location block.

Comment: The `location` only looks at the URI up to but not including the `?` and query string. You will need to test `$arg_` variables with an evil if or a map.

Answer (score 1):

Add a location block to process the `/shop/` URI, with a conditional `return` at the top.

The `$arg_` variable below, contains the value of the `query_type_product-categories` argument, of which the first two characters are tested:

```
location = /shop/ {
    if ($arg_query_type_product-categories ~ ^or) {
        return 403;
    }
    ...
}
```

Not sure what goes in the `...`, maybe a `try_files`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) for more. And [this](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) for caution about if.

Comment: Awesome thanks Richard. This definitely gets me going in the right direction so I really appreciate it.